# How can a new feature be created automatically, depending on the editing in another layer?

Tags: qgis

I would like to record data in layer 1 which, depending on the values of an attribute, create a new data record in layer 2.

Is this possible in QGIS 3.16 without phyton?

Comment: Can you please show an example of your input and desired output?

Comment: You actually need new features or would it be OK to just get symbolization (for visual purposes only)?

Comment: My input is a new feature in an existing point layer (layer 1), which is inserted manually. It fills the feature with a certain attribute, should this create a new feature in another point layer (layer 2). The new feature in layer 2 contains the location from layer 1 and the specific attributes.
The features including the symbol are required.

Comment: You should be able to do this using a virtual layer.